# Document Location Index of but not equal to

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

As the title says, I'm trying to use an if statement in jQuery for all pages that are a child of 'Portfolio' but not the portfolio page itself. So far I've tried..

```
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('portfolio') > -1 || document.location.pathname != "/portfolio/" ) {
}
```

to no avail

Comment: And what doesn't work ?

Comment: The code you mention is [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), and contains nothing of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). The former is a language, the latter a framework written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this might be a bit too restrictive:
document.location.pathname != "/portfolio/"

If your pathname is something like /portfolio/clients, then your test would fail. Perhaps also use an indexOf there too - like you do in your first conditional.

How about something along the lines of: Assuming someurl/portfolio/**somepath**

```
if(document.location.pathname.match(/portfolio(\/\w)+/)){
   console.log('we are in a child page')
}
```

so, someURL.com/portfolio  <-- would fail

so, someURL.com/portfolio/additionalpath <-- would pass